# Work with different branches at once

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, git-extensions

I have two branches of my solution in GIT. One is X branch and other is master. Both branches (local) points to same location(where physical files are say c:\Git\Myproject). I want to work simultaneously with those branches in diff VS solutions. But when I change the branch in one of the VS solutions my branch of other VS solution is changed and both the solutions points to same branch. How can I prevent this? I want to work with different branches at once.

Comment: Like i said in my (deleted) answer `Clone the repository multiple times and checkout different branches on each clone.`, if you don't know what that means, i'd recommend reading a git book. Other ppl are welcome to copy/paste and elaborate more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the `git-new-worktree` contrib script to create as many work trees (working directories) as needed.  Then, in each of them, you can check out any branch you want.

I don't know if it works on Windows, and I'm quite confident the GUI wrappers around Git you mentioned do not support calling that script, so you have to do some research.